# User opt-out with gtag.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, gtag.js

We're looking to implement the option for our website visitors to disable tracking.

I've read the Google Analytics [opt-out dev guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/user-opt-out) but I'm still not totally clear on how to do this.

Is it sufficient to just trigger `window['ga-disable-GA_TRACKING_ID'] = true;` when a button is clicked?

Will Google Analytics remember the setting for this user, or is it on a per-visit basis?

Can the user re-enable tracking if I have a second button that sets it to `false`?

Comment: Can anyone share some insight on this?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

I've literally just been trying to do this myself but not getting anywhere.

Comment: I did! Yesterday a friend of a friend helped me out. It's insane how hard it is to find this solution online. I've updated my question with the solution just now.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out! I've removed the "solved tag" from your title, as unlike on forums, it's not required on StackOverflow to indicate the presence of a working solution -- instead, click the "tick" icon next to the answer to mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 5):

Paste the following into the head tag before the Analytics code (replacing the UA with your own UA)

```
<script>
// Set to the same value as the web property used on the site
var gaProperty = 'UA-XXXX-Y';

// Disable tracking if the opt-out cookie exists.
var disableStr = 'ga-disable-' + gaProperty;
if (document.cookie.indexOf(disableStr + '=true') > -1) {
  window[disableStr] = true;
}

// Opt-out function
function gaOptout() {
  document.cookie = disableStr + '=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC; path=/';
  window[disableStr] = true;
}
</script>
```

And use this to trigger it:

```
<a href="javascript:gaOptout()">Click here to opt-out of Google Analytics</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply!

Since I replied to your post, I too came up with a solution but have yet to find a way of removing the cookie if a user chooses to opt out. While data doesn't get sent back to Google, it would just be nice to remove the cookie for completion. Here's what I came up with.

```
<script async type="text/javascript">

function optIn() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('aValue', false);
}

function optOut() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('aValue', true);
    setCookie('_gat_gtag_TRACKING-ID', 'value', 0); 

}

var getCookieValue = sessionStorage.getItem('aValue');

var b = (getCookieValue == 'true');

window['ga-disable-TRACKING-ID'] = b;

</script>
```

And this is triggered by

```
<form class="form-inline">
<button value="optin" onClick="optIn();" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Opt In</button>
<br />
<button value="optout" onClick="optOut();" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Opt Out</button>
</form>
```

So what this is doing is setting window['ga-disable-TRACKING-ID'] to either true or false, depending on the visitors response, which gets stored in SessionStorage. Hope this helps anyone as well as the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

[GTag Opt In](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gtag-opt-in) is a tool that does it for you plus allows you to have cookies disabled by default and enable them later, disable again, enable again, and so on.

### Disable cookies

```
   <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXX-Y"></script>
-- <script>
-- window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
-- function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
-- gtag('js', new Date());
-- gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXX-Y');
-- </script>
```

At the point where GA is implemented, this needs to be updated by just importing the `gtag.js` script and removing the GA initialisation.

### Enable GTag when user accepts cookies

[GTag Opt In](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gtag-opt-in) is a tool that enable and disable GA when user accepts/rejects cookies.

```
<script src="https://www.npmcdn.com/gtag-opt-in@2.0.0/dist/index.js"></script>

<script>
  GTagOptIn.register('UA-XXXXXX-Y');
</script>

<a href="javascript:GTagOptIn.optIn()">ACCEPT</a>
<a href="javascript:GTagOptIn.optOut()">REJECT</a>
```

First, library is loaded.
Second, the GA tracking ID is registered.
Third, the `optIn` and `optOut` functions are bind to user actions' accept/reject.

You can read more about it on [How To Implement Google Analytics With Opt In](https://medium.com/@delucioux/how-to-implement-google-analytics-with-opt-in-b19674d0bf86).