# Unload/remove/disable Google Analytics dynamically without a full page load

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, gtag.js

I see various guides on how to add Google Analytics/ GA into a page dynamically, e.g. for a Single Page Application/ SPA.

How can I do the reverse, i.e. a user clicks a button and Google Analytics is completely *removed* from that page, without a full page load?

The instructions at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/user-opt-out suggesting to set

```
window['ga-disable-GA_MEASUREMENT_ID'] = true;
```

I don't think helps doing this, since the page states

> This window property must be set before any calls to gtag() are made

Comment: You want completely remove? whether disabling it wil do?

Comment: @PramodNikam Disabling will do, but ideally, completely remove.

Comment: You can disable it at the very least and remove upon next refresh. You could try removing the script tag from head but I am not sure if that works. You can also remove the cookies set by google in js

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by refreshing the page on opt-out and setting:

```
window['ga-disable-TRACKING-ID'] = true;
```

before gtag is loaded.

More detail here:
[User opt-out with gtag.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48468226/user-opt-out-with-gtag-js)

to disable tracking (not all) without reload:

```
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', { 'send_page_view': false })
gtag('set', 'allow_ad_personalization_signals', false)
```

Comment: Understood, but the question is how to do this _without_ refreshing the page.

Comment: `gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', { 'send_page_view': false })` and `gtag('set', 'allow_ad_personalization_signals', false)`

Comment: or don't use default gtag, but some library -- for example in my react project I use https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga and with it you have full control over logged data and can disable it easily

Comment: that react lib is just a wrapper for gtag.  it also looks like a lot of code to basically do the same think i have suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this problem a bit differently than I have seen posted anywhere.   The app I'm working on tracks globally but also needs to track content that's own by an org for that org.

so i don't do this

```
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID)
```

and instead use the `send_to` field. which basically looks something like

```
const measurementIds = [ GA_MEASUREMENT_ID_1, GA_MEASUREMENT_ID_2 ];
measurementIds.forEach(id => {
  gtag('event', 'page_view', { send_to: id });
})
```

as users go in out of various content I add or remove their ID to the `measurementIds` array.